# assign function does not work when piping to second argument

Tags: r, pipe, assign

I'm trying to assign a value to a variable using pipes. However, I get the following error.

```
> 1 %>% assign("a", .)
> a
Error: object 'a' not found
```

The following does not work either

```
> "a2" %>% assign(., 1)
> a2
Error: object 'a2' not found
```

Writing to stdout does not work either

```
> write(1, stdout()) %>% assign("a3", .)
1
> a3
Error: object 'a3' not found
```

How do I fix this?
Thank you.

Comment: Piping is a `dplyr` functionality. `write` doesn't return anything. However, if you were to use a function that actually returns something, like `which`, you could nest `assign`, i.e., `that. = c(1, 3, 5)` followed by `assign("a3", which(that == 3))`, you would find the object `a3` set to 2 (since `which` returned the index value).

Comment: Why not `a <- 1`, the standard syntax? (Or `1 -> a`) Are you trying to do something in particular that is motivating your use of `assign`?

Comment: Using the base pipe it works, e.g. `1 |> assign("a", value = _)`.  It's a bug in the `magrittr` pipe.

Comment: I'm trying to create multiple variables using assign in a loop. Thank you very much!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Specify the environment to assign into when using a magrittr pipe:

```
library(magrittr)
if (exists("a")) rm(a)
1 %>% assign("a", ., .GlobalEnv)
a
## [1] 1
```

or use the magrittr eager pipe

```
if (exists("a")) rm(a)
1 %!>% assign("a", .)
a
## [1] 1
```

Alternately use the native R pipe.

```
if (exists("a")) rm(a)
1 |> assign("a", value = _)
a
## [1] 1
```

With `stdout()` it must be captured first:

```
if (exists("a3")) rm(a3)
write(1, stdout()) %>% capture.output %>% assign("a3", ., .GlobalEnv)
a3
## [1] 1

if (exists("a3")) rm(a3)
write(1, stdout()) %>% capture.output %!>% assign("a3", .)
a3
## [1] 1

if (exists("a3")) rm(a3)
write(1, stdout()) |> capture.output() |> assign("a3", value = _)
a3
## [1] 1
```